# Основы геометрии | Python

Tags: python, геометрия

Point объекты имеют атрибуты x y. Напишите функцию, вычисляющую расстояние между Point a и Point b. Тесты округляют ответы до 6 знаков после запятой. | CodeWars

Данную задачу я решил, но мой ввод подразумевает point = [x, y], а не point(x, y):

Само решение произвёл на координатной плоскости. Достаточно, используя знания о координатах, начертить прямоугольник, где отрезок AB - диагональ, которую мы найдём так: `sqrt(so**2 + st**2)`
Где so и st стороны прямоугольника. Используем теорему пифагора.

[image: Иллюстрация]

Мой код:

```
from math import *
def distance_between_points(a, b):
    if a[0]>b[0]:
        storona_one = a[0]-b[0]
    else:
        storona_one = b[0]-a[0]
        
    if a[1]>b[1]:
        storona_two = a[1]-b[1]
    else:
        storona_two = b[1]-a[1]
        
    d = sqrt(storona_two**2+storona_one**2)
```

Задача, которую я не могу понять - изменить решение из формата массивов в формат ()

Тесты:

```
import codewars_test as test
from solution import distance_between_points
from preloaded import Point

@test.describe("Fixed Tests")
def fixed_tests():
    @test.it('Basic Test Cases')
    def basic_test_cases():
        test.assert_equals(distance_between_points(Point(3, 3), Point(3, 3)), 0)
        test.assert_equals(distance_between_points(Point(1, 6), Point(4, 2)), 5)
        test.assert_equals(round(distance_between_points(Point(-10.2, 12.5), Point(0.3, 14.7)), 6), 10.728001)
```

Comment: https://pythobyte.com/tuple-to-list-51871b01/

Comment: В скобках заметим что `if`-ы не нужны, т.к. при возведении в квадрат всё равно получится неотрицательное число.

Comment: "Point объекты имеют атрибуты x y. " - значит, что к полю x нужно обращаться как `a.x`, а на `a[0]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ввод в примере не `point = (x, y)`, а `Point(x, y)` что совершенно разные записи: в первой создается кортеж, а во второй объект класса `Point`.
Вот проблема в том, что в классе `Point` обращение происходит не по индексу, а по переменной объекта:
`p = Point(1, 2); print(p.x, p.y)`
Однако без кода класса трудно точно сказать как правильно получить `x` и `y` из переданного в функцию объекта.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, данная тема входит в ООП?

Comment: Вот это задание: https://www.codewars.com/kata/58dced7b702b805b200000be Кода нет, но явно сказано что точка задаётся атрибутами `x` и `y`.

Comment: @Alexander_K от ооп в этой задаче мало. если и входит то на на минимальном уровне